# Android RxJava Retrofit MVVM RecyclerView does not show up

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am implementing a RecyclerView in a fragment. The XML should be correct since I tried it with my hard-coded data, and the API call does return the correct json data from the server according to the Log in the console. The problem is that the RecyclerView adapter does not get any data from my Observable. Here is my implementation

In PostDataService interface I used Retrofit to get an Observable>

```
interface PostDataService {

    @GET(".")
    fun getPosts(
        @Query(value = "offset") offset: Long = 0,
        @Query(value = "limit") limit: Long = 10,
        @Query(value = "subscribedOnly") subscribedOnly: Boolean = false
    ): Observable<List<Post>>

    companion object {
        val retrofit: PostDataService = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http:aws/api/post/")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
            .create(PostDataService::class.java)
    }
}
```

In PostListRepository, I used RxJava operators to get the LiveData

```
class PostListRepository {

    private val postListLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<Post>> = MutableLiveData()
    private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    fun getPostListLiveData(): MutableLiveData<List<Post>> {
        val postList: MutableList<Post> = ArrayList()
        val retrofitInstance = PostDataService.retrofit
        val postListObservable = retrofitInstance.getPosts()
        compositeDisposable.add(
            postListObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMapIterable { it }
                .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<Post>() {
                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        // if some error happens in our data layer our app will not crash, we will
                        // get error here
                    }

                    override fun onNext(post: Post) {
                        postList.add(post)
                    }

                    override fun onComplete() {
                        postListLiveData.postValue(postList)
                    }
                })
        )
        return postListLiveData
    }

    fun clear() {
        compositeDisposable.clear()
    }
}
```

In PostListViewModel, I passed the LiveData from the repository into this ViewModel.

```
class PostListViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var postListRepository: PostListRepository = PostListRepository()

    fun getPostList(): MutableLiveData<List<Post>> {
        return postListRepository.getPostListLiveData()
    }

    fun clear() {
        postListRepository.clear()
    }
}
```

Here is the Fragment that contains the RecyclerView. I think the `.oberserve` function in `getPostList()` is not called since I tried Log it but got nothing.

```
class PostListFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var swipeLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout
    private lateinit var postListViewModel: PostListViewModel
    private val postListAdapter = PostRecyclerViewAdapter()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_post_list, container, false)
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.postRecyclerView)
        recyclerView.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            addItemDecoration(VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(36))
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = postListAdapter
        }

        postListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PostListViewModel::class.java)
        getPostList()

        swipeLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeLayout)
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary)
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
            getPostList()
            swipeLayout.isRefreshing = false
        }
        return rootView
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        postListViewModel.clear() // to avoid memory leak
    }

    private fun getPostList() {
        postListViewModel.getPostList().observe(this, Observer<List<Post>> { resource ->
            postListAdapter.setPostList(resource)
            postListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the adapter for the RecyclerView:

```
class PostRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostViewHolder>() {

    private var postList: List<Post> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val postView = PostView(parent.context)
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        return PostViewHolder.from(postView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = postList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val curPost = postList[position]
        holder.postView.apply {
            setPostOwnerDisplayName(curPost.content.userDisplayedName)
            setPostOwnerRole(curPost.content.role)
            setPostOwnerAvatar(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            setPostText(curPost.content.text)
            setPostImage(curPost.content.smallMediaPaths[0])
            setLikeState(curPost.liked)
            setBookmarkState(curPost.bookmarked)
        }
    }

    fun setPostList(postList: List<Post>) {
        this.postList = postList
    }
}
```

As I mentioned above, I think the `.oberserve` function in `getPostList()` in `PostListFragment` is not called since I tried Log it but got nothing, so there is no data passed into the RecyclerView. Can anyone help me find the reason why it's not being called, or why it's not getting the data from the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that I forgot to catch the exception in RxJava `onNext()` in case to get the moshi serialization error. After getting that, I got some moshi conversion errors.
Posted it in case anyone carelessly forgot to catch the moshi error. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think of this is related to your issue, but your code has potential problems.

1. To move `observe` part to `onActivityCreated` would be better to ensure view is created.
2. when your fragment view is re-created, a new `Observer` will be added, while previous one still alive, because your `Observer` is anonymous. So, you have to manage the observers to prevent it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't quite get why I need to do the fragment stuffs in the parent activity? and I thought when the fragment is destroyed in `onDestroy()`, the observes would be gone because that's also where I also cleared my viewmodels?

Comment: First, `onActivityCreated()` is one of the fragment lifecycle! Second, fragment `onDestroyView()` could be called without `onDestroy()`. In this case, fragment instance is still alive, while view is destroyed.